# Does SQLite or any its extension support prefix compression?

Tags: sqlite

My key indexes are of string type and have common prefixes. For example,

```
aaa.bbb.c
aaa.bbb.d
aaa.bbb.d.eee
```

Some data bases compress indexes by sharing common prefixes. https://blogs.oracle.com/dbstorage/compressing-your-indexes:-index-key-compression-part-1

Does SQLite have any extension or plugin that supports this?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such code.

You could write your own [virtual table](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) for this.